# Connecting to amazon ec2 instance with ssh - timeout

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2

every time I try to connect to my amazon instance my ssh client (Putty) times out. I have disabled all firewalls I could find (Router, windows built-in) and enabled ssh in security groups. Event log from putty: 
2012-01-06 22:04:15 Looking up host "ec2-50-x-x-222.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com"
2012-01-06 22:04:15 Connecting to 50.x.x.222 port 22
2012-01-06 22:04:36 Failed to connect to 50.x.x.222: Network error: Connection timed out
2012-01-06 22:04:36 Network error: Connection timed out

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Have you converted your "pem" to "ppk"?

Answer (score 2):

Did you set up a key in EC2?

[blog entry on ec2 keys etc](http://chris-richardson.blog-city.com/amazon_ec2_keypairs_and_other_stumbling_blocks_1.htm)

and

[another good one](http://www.keywordintellect.com/amazon-web-services/managing-an-amazon-ec2-instance-using-putty-ssh/)

Comment: k check your instance and look at the Security Groups applied to it.  MAybe the port isn't open on there.

Comment: I tried to ping the IP address of the instance, but all of the requests timed out. Could the problem be there? How do I fix it if that's the problem?

Comment: your instance is probably set by default to reject ICMP traffic, which a "ping" is doing.  see [this link](http://www.computing.net/answers/networking/what-ports-do-ping-use/24183.html) regarding iptables

Comment: I had a similar issue.  Under Security Groups -> Inbound -> TCP, is port 22 listed?  I think you may have to manually add it by "create a new rule" and then selecting SSH.

Comment: As @andrewj stated, you should manually add port 22. And choose 'Anywhere' as your source option. Also, maybe it is a good idea to try a port other than 22, just for added security, even though you are using private/public key pair.